# regex for substring on a string then replace text

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that I'm reading as:

```
with open(file,'r+') as f:
   file_data = f.read()
```

the `file_data` is a long string that has the following text:

```
'''This file starts here dig_1 = hello\n doge ras = friend\n sox = pie\n'''
```

I want to search for `dig_1` then get all the text after the `'='` up to the new line character `\n` and replace it with a different text so that it is `dig_1 = hello\n` is now `dig_1 = unknown` and do the same with the others (`ras = friend\n` to `ras = unknown` and `sox = pie\n` to `sox = unknown`).  Is there an easy way to do this using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `sub` function of python's `re` module
The pattern that you want to replace looks something like **a word followed by an equal sign and space and also has a preceding newline**

```
# import re module
import re

# original text
txt = '''This file starts here dig_1 = hello\n doge ras = friend\n sox = pie\n''' 

# pattern to look for
pattern = '= (.*?\n)'
# string to replace with
repl = 'unknown'

# replace 'pattern' with the string inside 'repl' in the string 'txt'
re.sub(pattern, repl, txt)
'This file starts here dig_1 unknown doge ras unknown sox unknown'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `re.sub` here:

```py
inp = "This file starts here dig_1 = hello\n doge ras = friend\n sox = pie\n"
output = re.sub(r'\b(\S+)\s*=\s*.*(?=\n|$)', r'\1 = unknown', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
This file starts here dig_1 = unknown
 doge ras = unknown
 sox = unknown
```